# How could I Encrypt OData Request Payload at Client Side(DataServiceContext) and Decrypting Request at ServerSide?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api, odata, httprequest

I have an Windows Application consuming `OData v4` WebAPI using `DataServiceContext`. WebApi is over SSL but still I think anyone can trap request using Web Debugging Tools like fiddler (on the Windows Application Host Machine) and can re-issue the request by altering Request Body.

So I was just thinking what if I could encrypt `RequestBody` of outgoing Request in Windows Application using Public/Private Key in Production Environment. If yes how could I?

Do I need to create custom `DataServiceClientRequestMessage` or need to hook encryption process somewhere in `DataServiceContext`.

The Request would be decrypted using `MessageHandler`.

[ServiceStack Encrypted Messaging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Encrypted-Messaging)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can write your custom `DataServiceClientRequestMessage`, and overwrite `GetStream()` to encrypt the output stream. 
Then, set the new message to DataServiceContext with `DataServiceContext.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnMessageCreating = new CustomRequestMessage()`.

You can refer a custom `DataServiceClientRequestMessage` example at OData github repository. [TestDataServiceClientRequestMessage.cs](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/cae9bbb85b5a45cc03dc42eec84f5e9eb1a41ed9/test/FunctionalTests/Tests/DataServices/UnitTests/ClientExtensions/TestDataServiceClientRequestMessage.cs) and [DataServiceContextWithCustomTransportLayer.cs](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/cae9bbb85b5a45cc03dc42eec84f5e9eb1a41ed9/test/FunctionalTests/Tests/DataServices/UnitTests/ClientExtensions/DataServiceContextWithCustomTransportLayer.cs)