# How could I Modify Odata POST/PATCH/PUT Request JSON Payload

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, odata

How could I modify OData JSON payload before sending to the server? I am Using DataServiceContext to interact with WebApi OData Service.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [BuildingRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.buildingrequest(v=vs.113).aspx) event on [DataServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Hi @lencharest, As I mentioned that I would like to modify JSON Request Message Content, but in this event there is no provision to modify Message Content.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are look for is **request pipeline**, which can modify the payload before sending. Please refer:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2013/07/26/using-the-new-client-hooks-in-wcf-data-services-client/

Comment: Hi Zeo, Thanks for the reply but I went through the link but didn't found useful. As I can just modify an entity, not the JSON generated for Request.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of modification you want? Since the entities will be converted to json in the end, can your modification convert to operations on entity or feed?

Comment: I want to encrypt Content using Public Key and at Server, it would be decrypted

Comment: Hope this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455480) would help you assist me.